# android VideoView increase buffering

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have writen a video player that plays videos from a website. My videoplayer is actualy the VideoView gadget from android.

The videos are playing ok when I am on the wifi network, the things are not the same if I switch to 3G as expected :D. What I want is to increase the streaming buffer, it seems that VideoView is streaming the video up to 8% of the clip size.

When I press the play button, the streaming its still coming but it keeps that percentage distance... and if I press pause, the streaming is stopping..

Can I increase the streaming length and make the video streaming while in pause?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly read the stream yourself to a local file and point the VideoView to that. I'm not sure however how much you're allowed to store. Also, will the VideoView react well the fixed size of the file as it was pointed to. You could possibly create the file in correct size, but then you will have to make sure that video is not read beyond the point you have cached.

Comment: I think that this could be a little bit expensive method... I though that the videoview could have the features that I need but I am not aware of... Thank you for your answer anyway.  I will take a look on the VideoView's source code and see if I can do something...

Comment: Cata did u find a solution for this buffering size increase problem? I am facing a similar issue...